# Separating submeshes into meshes

Tags: mesh, materials, export, import, gltf

I've got a Sponza scene in gltf. In order to debug some stuff in my engine I want to delete some parts of the scene.

Now, when I'm importing it into Blender, I see that the scene is just one mesh and all the submeshes are treated as different materials.

Can I somehow turn all the submeshes into separate meshes so that I could delete them if I need to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Edit Mode, *Mesh > Separate > By Material* (shortcut: P).